# Get a double from a long created from Double.toLongBits

Tags: java, types, double, decimal, long-integer

Is there a way to reverse a `long` I got from `Double.toLongBits` back to a `Double`?
The following does not work:

```
Double n = 171.30672219;
System.out.println(Double.doubleToLongBits(n));
System.out.println(new Double(Double.doubleToLongBits(n)));
```

this prints:

> 4640231336019091517
> 4.6402313360190915E18

While I wanted to get back the `171.30672219`

Answer (score 6):

As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits-double-) for `doubleToLongBits` says:

> In all cases, the result is a long integer that, when given to the `longBitsToDouble(long)` method, will produce a floating-point value the same as the argument to `doubleToLongBits` (except all NaN values are collapsed to a single "canonical" NaN value).

```
double n = 171.30672219;
System.out.println(Double.doubleToLongBits(n));
System.out.println(Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(n)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
Double n = 171.30672219;
long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(n);
double d = Double.longBitsToDouble(bits);
System.out.println(d);
```

prints

```
171.30672219
```

Welcome to the world of [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).